# Squid regex syntax description?

Tags: squid

From [abuse.ch](https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/api/) one can get a plain text file with malware distributing URIs. I want to use this as a blacklist for squid proxy (not yet sure about runtime behavior).  It should not be to hard to convert the URI file into a regex file for `acl aclname url_regex ...` using `sed`, but I struggle to find the squid regex syntax description to identify all special characters, that I have to escape.

Comment: the dquid page has a nice wiki, https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl

Comment: I know this wiki page, but it describes the acl syntax, not the regex syntax.

Comment: You must be more specific and produce at least one example clearly stating what you intend to do. Anyway, assuming you just need to parse a hosts file [https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/downloads/hostfile/](https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/downloads/hostfile/), you may try this: search for `^(#.*$(\n|\r\n)?|127.*\t)` and replace with `""`

Comment: I'm looking for a description of the regex syntax itself. Which metacharacters, quantifiers, modifiers, ... are allowed, This differs slightly from perl to php to java to ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squid understands **GNUregex** (Extended Regular Expressions, AKA: *ERE REGEXP*). 
It does not fully understand Perl Regular Expressions, AKA: *PCRE*. 

E.x: *\w, \d, \W, \D, lookahead, negative lookahead, shy grouping, atomic groups, etc.*..)

Working examples:

```
^(outlook-[1-9]\.cdn|attachments|res\.cdn)\.office\.net$
^c[0-9]+.*(powerpoint|word|excel|visio).*[0-9]{2}\.cdn\.office\.net$
^trello-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.s3\.amazonaws\.com$
```

NON WORKING examples but PCRE valid:

```
^(outlook-\d\.cdn|attachments|res\.cdn)\.office\.net$
^c\d+.*(powerpoint|word|excel|visio).*\d{2}\.cdn\.office\.net$
^trello-\w+\.s3\.amazonaws\.com$
^rr?[1-9]-{2,4}sn-(?!.*-apn[a-z]).*\.googlevideo\.com)$
```

More info:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expressions.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: While I think @mjoao is right, I would prefer him/her to add a link to the relevant SQUID configuration supporting such an answer.